# How to send asynchronous mail?

Tags: php

It will take time to send the mail to the user and executing the code up to the Location header. I want to run the mail sending code in another thread so it will not take time to locate or load that particular page.

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM user_info where username = ?";

        $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(1, $cmtTo);
        $statement->execute();

        $row = $statement->fetch();

//        echo $row['email'];

        $mailSender = new PuzzleEmailSender();
        $body = "<html>
                    <body>
            <h2 style=\"font-weight:bold;font-size:24px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;line-height:26px;color:#999;margin:0\"><img class=\"navbarimg\"  src=\"" alt=\"/></h2><br>
                            <div style=\"font:normal 14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;line-height:19px;color:#333\">
                <p>Hi, <strong>" . $cmtTo . "</strong> </p>
                                <p><strong>" . $cmtBy . "</strong> expressed comment on your puzzle answer</strong></p>
                <p><a style=\"text-decoration:underline;color:#00aff0;font-weight:bold\" href='" "' target=\"_blank\">Click on the link to check</a></p>                                
                <p>Team,</p>
                <p style=\"font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;line-height:24px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#666;margin:0\">
                " "</p></div>
                            </div>
                    </body>
        </html>";

        $subject = "Comment On Your Answer";

        $mailSender->sendQueryEmail($row['email'], "", $body, $subject, "", false);

        header("Location: puzzleDisplay");
```

Comment: Put the mail sending in to its own file. Call that with `exec`

Comment: Sending a single mail does not take long. It's not worth the hassle of creating another thread or a cronjob for it.

Comment: in this case you should check laravel jobs

Comment: that exec file call will never work in php mail sending

Answer (score 1):

create table: **mail_queue**

fields: **id, email, subject, body**

change:

```
$mailSender->sendQueryEmail($row['email'], "", $body, $subject, "", false);
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mail_queue SET email = ?, body = ?, subject = ?"
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(1, $row['email']);
$statement->bindParam(2, $body);
$statement->bindParam(3, $subject);
$statement->execute();
```

create script: **mail_queue.php** that will do fetch all emails and do mail send and then delete record after send

put to crontab: *** * * * * php mail_queue.php**

Answer (score 0):

You can send the mail in background. Add the mailing task to some queue and then the queue will be executed time to time.

These can be achieved in many ways:

- You can use a persistent storage queue. Like you store the mail into
  DB. Then a script from cron will check unsent mails and send them one
  by one.
- You can use `gearman-job-server`. Enqueue your mail in the job server
  from your main script. Then write code for sending email in `gearman worker` scripts.
- You can use hosted queue service solutions like:  `iron.io` . Laravel
  queue uses iron api.